# How does SEO work when redirecting to a different site/domain

Tags: redirects, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could I buy a domain name to increase traffic to my site like this?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this)

I have a site (e.g. www.foo.bar).  When someone attempts to browse this site, they are redirected to a different site (e.g. www.test.com).  I only reason of having foo.bar is because of the domain name.  test.com is a 3rd party.  I want people to come to foo.bar, so I can market on the domain name.  If I am selling parts (e.g. Ford car parts).  I want to configure SEO so that my domain name and "Ford car parts" are associated.  The intention is when someone googles "foo.bar" and "Ford car parts" search engines start ranking my site/domain.  foo.bar isnt the site housing the sale of the parts....the 3rd party is, but I would like to SEO woo.foo.bar if possible to accomplish my intention.  Is what I am looking to do possible?