# What Ranking Factors Are Used For International Search?

Tags: seo, top-level-domains, ranking, international

Google.com vs Google.ca vs Google.co.uk (etc) all rank their results differently. The intention is to return more locally-relevant content.

**What factors, other than the ones below, are used to determine local relevancy?**

I already know the TLD (.com, .ca, etc) and likely the server IP address is used but there has to be more as this would not explain some search results I noticed this week.

Particularly, I see a US-based site ranking #3 for some keywords on Google.com, ranking #5 on Google.ca and not ranking within the first pages on Google.co.uk. On Google.com it outranks a Australian site which outranks it on Google.ca. The site itself is relevant for all English-speaking locations and it being outranked by sites from different regions on different Google TLDs (but not ones from the same region as the TLD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google: Working with multi-regional websites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html)

> Google generally uses the following
>   elements to determine the geotargeting
>   of a website (or a part of a website):
>
> **Use of a ccTLD** is generally a strong signal for users since it
>   explicitly specifies a single country
>   in an unmistakable way.
>
> or
>
> **Webmaster Tools' manual geotargeting for gTLDs** (this can be on a domain,
>   subdomain or subdirectory level); more
>   information on this can be found in
>   our blog post and in the Help Center.
>   With region tags from geotargeting
>   being shown in search results, this
>   method is also very clear to users.
>   Please keep in mind that it generally
>   does not make sense to set a
>   geographic target if the same pages on
>   your site target more than a single
>   country (say, all German-speaking
>   countries) — just write in that
>   language and do not use the
>   geotargeting setting (more on writing
>   in other languages will follow soon!).
>
> **Server location** (through the IP address of the server) is frequently
>   near your users. However, some
>   websites use distributed content
>   delivery networks (CDNs) or are hosted
>   in a country with better webserver
>   infrastructure, so we try not to rely
>   on the server location alone.
>
> **Other signals can give us hints**. This could be from local addresses &
>   phone numbers on the pages, use of
>   local language and currency, links
>   from other local sites, and/or the use
>   of Google's Local Business Center
>   (where available).
>
> Note that we do not use locational
>   meta tags (like "geo.position" or
>   "distribution") or HTML attributes for
>   geotargeting. While these may be
>   useful in other regards, we've found
>   that they are generally not reliable
>   enough to use for geotargeting.

Other then giving more weight to local web pages the ranking factors are the same. It is important to note that being in a specific country doesn't mean you'm automatically rank well or better then non-country specific web pages. Quality of content still is the most important factor.

Comment: Guess I am seeing the impact of *links from local-sites* cause some less relevant (actually *irrelevant( in some cases) to outrank me in localized search. What do you think would be the impact then of having a ccTLD that redirects to a gTLD site? Would the hint be taken or ignored since a 301 would be returned?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this/3778#3778) for why that won't work.