# What are pitfalls in SEO when internationalizing a website?

Tags: internationalization, path, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Ranking Factors Are Used For International Search?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15927/what-ranking-factors-are-used-for-international-search)

There are 2 basic ways I have been looking into to make a website multilingual:

---

**1. subdirectory/subdomain alias**

e.g. *www.example.com/en/path* or *en.example.com*

The server identifies the "en" in the path and returns language-specific content.

*This is great* because you can share and bookmark language-specific links without dependency on a user's previous selection.

---

**2. cookie-based, or session-based, server-side content swap**

e.g. *www.example.com/path*

The server identifies the presence of a cookie, which is given to the user when they click on the language they want, and shows content.  The path is the same for both versions.

*This is great because* it makes path and menu management easy, and avoids "duplicate content" on your site.

---

Is either approach an accepted standard?

**For Option 1:**
How do search engines handle the translations?  Will they be able to index the translated content if it's only served when a cookie is detected?  What happens if default is english, and I support Spanish, and somebody enters a google search in spanish?

**For Option 2:**
Will you get docked for duplicate content using Option 2?

Comment: May I suggest you read these two articles on Google's webmasters blog very carefully: [one about multi-regional sites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html) and [one about multi-lingual sites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html) The last one being of specific interest to you, I think. But **do** read about the distinction made in the two articles.

Comment: or i guess that's thanks fireeyedboy (other comment disamapeared)