# Is it good for SEO to have domain alias that describes company service?

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, keywords, alternative

I have bought a domian that is like `service.city.example`
Where service is eg. "haircut".

Is it good to have this kind of domains as aliases to main domain `company.example`?

What would be best for SEO, serving the main domain content on this alias or redirect 301 from alias to main domain?

Answer (score 0):

Alternate and alias domains have no effect on SEO.  Owning `service.city.example` won't help your business rank for your "service city" on Google.  See [What should I do with a ton of alternate domains? Redirect or use landing pages?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16563/what-should-i-do-with-a-ton-of-alternate-domains-redirect-or-use-landing-pages)

Having a domain that matches your keywords used to be a great way to rank if you actually used that domain (as opposed to just using it as an alias).   Such a domain is known as an "exact match domain" or EMD because the keywords in the domain exactly match the keywords you are targeting.   In 2012 [Google launched an EMD algorithm](https://searchengineland.com/library/google/emd-update) that made it such that using and EMD didn't help rankings.   As far as I can tell, that update worked.   It doesn't even help to use your keyword rich domain as your main domain anymore for SEO.