# Alias Domain SEO Impact

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, alias

I am a bit afraid that google will punish us as of duplicate content. Let's say there are three domains.

- `service_a.example`
- `service_b.example`
- `mycompany.example`

All three domains shall share the same Colors/Styles/CI, so I want to have all sources in one place. If I change the button color, all three domains should update.

**Idea:** `mycompany.example` is the main domain which has a path `/service_a` and `/service_b`. I want to configure NGINX that way that if a user visits `service_a.example` the content of `mycompany.example/service_a` gets served. My idea is just to add a canonical link from `https://service_a.example` to `https://mycompany.com/service_a`.

Comment: See also [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site):  Google doesn't usually punish for duplicate content, it usually chooses to ignore all but one of the duplicates.

Comment: Another relevant question: [What should I do with a ton of alternate domains? Redirect or use landing pages?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16563/what-should-i-do-with-a-ton-of-alternate-domains-redirect-or-use-landing-pages)

Comment: The difference here is that I don't want to redirect. If the user finds us via paid ads because he is looking for service_a, I don't want to redirect to mycompany.example because it would confuse the visitor maybe. 

I'd rather leave him on service_a.example. As soon as we sold something to the client I want to tell him that under my company.example he will find all our services.

I don't want to get more SEO traffic, I just don't want to get punished from google if I have three domains and two of them have a canonical link to the primary one.

Comment: That is why the question about duplicate content is relevant.  Google almost never "punishes" for it.

Comment: Ok got it, just read the two other links. My fault. "If your site must return the same content under multiple URLs (e.g. for a "print view" page) specify a canonical URL manually with a link element in the document header". So my approach should not have any bad impact on my domain my company.example. Thank you very much.