# Keywords in domain name

Tags: seo, domains, 301-redirect, keywords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could I buy a domain name to increase traffic to my site like this?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this)

Let's assume we have a generic website "**MyWebsiteAboutGamesAndThings.com**".  We discover that a lot of people are searching for "**Make games**".

We find that the domain name **MakeGames.com** is free so we register it with the assumption that a keyword specific domain such as this will rank favorably for the search term we have discovered.

We now have two options with the domain name:

- We can 301 redirect **MakeGames.com** to **MyWebsiteAboutGamesAndThings.com**
- Or we can make a simple webpage on it that intends to feed visitors to **MyWebsiteAboutGamesAndThings.com**.

The reason for registering **MakeGames.com** was to target that specific search, however I have a feeling that you lose the benefit of the keywords in the domain by 301ing it.  Is it better to make a sort of landing website for **MakeGames.com**?  If you 301 the domain to **MyWebsiteAboutGamesAndThings.com** will it now rank better for the search **Make games**?  Which is a better method?

Comment: There is another question that covers the landing page question. Once I find it i'll link to that one, too.