# Do search engines index a new domain that just redirect to the main site?

Tags: seo, domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could I buy a domain name to increase traffic to my site like this?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this)

**Scenario:**
I have a site called for example `foodeals.com` and a new bought domain `greatfooforyou.com` that simply does a 301 redirect to the main site

**Question:**
do search engines index `greatfooforyou.com` at all?
Is it possible that, one day, searching for *"great foo for you"* keywords, I will find the `greatfooforyou.com` exploiting the exact match of the search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, no. You are indicating 301, which is a permanent redirect. There is no need to index that new domain. I have done this too (over a period of three years), to prevent others from hijacking similar domain names and they've never shown up in search results.

Comment: The only way a domain will appear in SERPs is if the domain had content and the content was replaced with a 301 and Google hasn't crawled the site yet.  Usually that is a very small window and if you report your updates to Google Webmasters it is even smaller.