# SEO a site from another site

Tags: seo, subdomain

I use a vendor who has a site for ordering parts.  The vendor sells many kinds of parts.  Is it possible to perform some kind of SEO magic, where I can SEO, or direct users, to the vendor's site?  For example, let's say the parts vendor sells car parts for all car manufacturers.  If I own a Chevy site and buy parts from this vendor (who sells Toyota, Cadillac parts also), I would like to target customers who google Chevy Parts through the use of my site.  Is this possible or is there a way this is possible?  Or could I do something with domains/sub domains somewhere.

Not really sure if buying a domain and creating a site to target users like this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Buying a domain, or using a subdomain, just to redirect to the other site [won't work](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this/3778#3778).
- The most "SEO" you can do for the other site is to link to their website using the anchor text you hope for them to rank well for. Since the pages those links are on is related to their pages those links will have some SEO value for the other site. The same applies to using the anchor text they hope to rank well for.