# Satellite website or redirect

Tags: seo

We're running a campaign for specific industries within our target market.

Our main web site has a page for each industry.

We also own domains for each industry i.e: FoodWidgets.com, ElectricalWidgets.com, ChemicalWidgets.com.

Of the following methods, which is likely to make the best SEO improvements:

1. Just link each domain to the main web site
2. Forward each domain to the relevant page on the main site e.g. FoodWidgets.com (302) redirects to http://www.MainSite.com/industries/food
3. Create a single page "satellite" web site for each domain with the same content as the industry page on the main site.

Answer (score 3):

You can create landing page for each domain and write useful content which looks like a selling tool or a selling news letter, it must be a sort of call to action and redirect your reader to your main website.

Optimize landing pages as well as the main website, and it is also a better idea to add the links of the landing page in sitemap of your main site.

Answer (score 1):

1. [This won't work how you think it will work](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this/3778#3778).
2. See #1
3. This will cause duplicate content issues [which is bad for SEO](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html).

See also, [Pros/Cons of Interlinked Landing Pages](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/108/randomben)

Comment: Thanks John. Is there a better method? Since we'll be using the specific industry domains on promotional material, our main concern is that using them does not *damage* the rankings of the main site?

Answer (score 0):

Create the landing pages on your main site and don't have satellite sites as they are just set up to trick search engines - Meaning you can get penalised on your main site if they are seen to be connected (which google can quite easily to find).