# Will having multiple domains with redirects to my main domain have an impact on search rankings?

Tags: domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could I buy a domain name to increase traffic to my site like this?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this)

If I register 10 or so related domain names and 301-redirect them all to appropriate pages within my website will this hurt or help google ratings? Or will it be a neutral event?

For example if I operated a daycare center would it be wise to purchase bostonchildcare.com, bostondaycare.com and bostonpreschool.com and then 301 redirect them to all to appropriate pages on my site?

Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't improve your rankings UNLESS visitors are visiting the links through public spaces (blog links, forum posts, q&a sites, etc).

But to just have domain for the sole purpose of redirecting without driving traffic to them will not help whether you have 100 or a 1000s of 301 domains.

Comment: Even if visitors are visiting through external backlinks to all of those domains, how would that improve ranking?

Answer (score 0):

No, It will not work, unless those links which are pointing to your site are relevant and are often visited . If they themselves are not being crawled, they are nothing more than islands. To improve your site rank, you need to have a path from some connected place, whats the point of having a path from some unhaunted islands(your 100 domains)

Answer (score 0):

Well your strategy is not bad but we need to see what gives you better ROI. you if we analyze your suggestion. you will spend every year 10 domain rent. if you analyze benefits you may get from it is almost nil as these domain will not have any back-links so redirecting wont help in ranking, so what i would suggest is spend that 10 domain renewal amount for link building of your current site, that will give you better ROI.