# Is a good technique to buy abandoned domains to get link juice?

Tags: seo, domains, backlinks, expires

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could I buy a domain name to increase traffic to my site like this?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this)

Yesterday I was discussing with a friend an idea he had. To promote your site about, for example, fashion (i.e. example.com), the idea is:

1. Find an expired domain (i.e. fashionsite.com) with a good amount of links from fashion websites (it is, a site that has been abandoned, but still keep a lot of inbound links).
2. Recreate the site structure (i.e. if you have inbound link that points to fashionsite.com/files/boots.html, you have to add a page that responds to this structure).
3. Add links from your new site (fashionsite.com) to the old one you want to promote (example.com) in order to give the link juice to your site.
4. Goto 1 until you cannot find more expired domains related to your site topic.

This is a non-trivial process that could take a lot of time, so the question is: worth it? has anybody tried something like this? In fact, maybe that's a well known technique my friend and I didn't hear about it... Definitely I believe we haven't discovered a new technique :)

NOTE: I've forget to explain that this idea is specifically to improve a site link building for Google, we are not interested in other search engines by the moment.

Comment: Sorry, but I believe that's not a duplicate: my question is about to take profit of existing links on an abandoned domain and the one you have linked is about to buy a related domain name and built it from scratch.

Comment: And as soon as people realise their links don't point where they used to and remove/change them?  It is a scummy tactic that you deserve to be penalised for, and also the benefit won't last long.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it would work although with the amount of time spent, you'd be better off guest blogging, writing press releases and making link bait, etc.

As even if you got a pr5 site (I know page rank is not such a good measure nowadays but bear with me) you'd just end up with a load of links coming from one domain. You'd be much better off having them come from different domains.