# Is there a point to redirecting our collection of purchased domains?

Tags: domains, dns, 301-redirect, parking

We have 200+ domain names that we have purchased to prevent them from being poached and misused. These additional domains are not indexed, crawled or linked to. Is there a point to actually setting them up as redirects to our primary site?

I am of the opinion that the only reason to redirect is if there is some chance a visitor might type it in by hand because they can't remember our URL.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There [won't be any SEO value](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this/3778#3778), but if they're related to your website or contain misspellings, (and they are 301 redirects) then there is no harm in doing this and you may get lucky every once in a while and get some traffic through them. Someone looking to purchase one of those domains may even find your website that way and you may even get a related link if they think your site is worth it. I wouldn't hold my breath, though!