# What is the best way to use multiple similar domains for a single business with SEO aspects?

Tags: seo, multiple-domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will having multiple domains improve my seo?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/will-having-multiple-domains-improve-my-seo)

**Scenario:** There are around 15 freshly registered domains. All the domains are intended to support a single business activity.

**Example:**

- something-useful.com
- something-extraordinary-useful.com
- extraordinary-useful-something.com
- useful-something.com
- etc...

What will be the best approach to use these domains to get benefit of SEO? Or to promote the business online?

What are the possible approaches to use these domains?

Comment: There is no good reason for a single business to have that many domains to promote a single brand. You might want to buy a few misspellings, but the use case you describe sounds very spammy. A legitimate business markets a website on the quality of the content, service, and user experience they deliver, not the number of keyword-stuffed domains they own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your 15 domains seem to be spammy, I think the best way to promote your business is to publish fresh and good content (no duplicate etc.) on these websites.

Then, you can link from these websites your business website (money site) to improve its ranking.

In my opinion, it's the best way to exploit this websites network but you need much time to work on good content.

Content is king!

Answer (score 3):

Of course, I don't know how smart the search engines are. But I know that they make money when the users find all that they want. For that reason, duplicate contents (and also - I think - more than just one website for a small business) is not acceptable.

You can use more than a website, but just if you need to promote different aspects of your business. For example, different products.

In conclusion, use one another website just if it is necessary **semantically**

Comment: @ marco panichiMultiple domains alternatively blocking the competitors from purchasing similar sounding domain names and share the searchers attention.