# Full Domain Name Or Acronym?

Tags: domains, url, name

I read on MOZ that a domain name should ideally be less than 15 characters. My current domain name for a WIP website is ANightInBurlington.com, which is 18 before the .com, and without http:// or www. My thoughts:

- While ANightInBurlington.com is a bit long, it contains both "Night" and "Burlington", the focus of my website (night life / tourism in Burlington, Vermont). "Burlington" is also a little long as it is, so it's only natural that anything with "Burlington" in it will be a tad long.
- My domain name, while long, is catchy and capable of branding.
- The primary reason to not go beyond 15 characters, is because users may not remember the name / may typo the URL when writing it. I don't think this is an issue with it mostly containing 2 words (not counting a and in).

My alternative URL is anibvt.com, which is an acronym for ANightInBurlington (adding VT to the end to specify Vermont / grab an available domain). My thoughts on this:

- Much shorter domain, only 6 characters!
- It's slightly catchy, though I'm not sure how memorable it is.
- It's not at all clear to search engines / users what the site is about by the domain name alone.

So with that information, I'm just wondering if anyone can weight in. I'm pretty happy with ANightInBurlington.com, but I just want some reassurance that the domain isn't too long, "Burlington" in the name has some value (to search engines and users), and that I'm essentially good to carry on as I am. If not, I'll gladly switch the name.

Comment: Sorry but this question type of question has been asked many times in various forms. To avoid further disappointment please visit our help center. Additionally you will find many related questions here by searching, i.e http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=domain+keyword

Comment: Another on topic question is http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/will-having-multiple-domains-improve-my-seo