# What to do with domains with alternative tlds

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

I tried to find this as I think it's a common issue but could not in the search.

I own a .com domain which is my main site but I also own other tlds for the same domain name such as .net, .mobi, .org, etc.

Is there something I should be doing to configure them somehow to be apart of my main .com site or should I just sit on them?

Comment: You do not provide enoug context/contraints to get back other answers than just personal opinions. You can configure them to be a redirect to your main `.com`, you can serve different content through them or you can just park them and not make them resolve. This all depends on many other points you did not describe.

Comment: See also: [Will having multiple domains improve my seo?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/will-having-multiple-domains-improve-my-seo)  They won't help SEO, so it is a matter of whether or not users ever type them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you have is to point them to the web server by either redirects in dns entries or do nothing. Your choice.