# If I buy a domain based on my personal name and redirect it to a blog, will my domain appear when people search for my name?

Tags: domains, google-search, redirects, search-engines, 302-redirect

I have a main webpage that ranks well in a specific city (`myprofession+city.com`). My problem is that I also want a personal domain (e.g., `JohnDoe.com`).

So I was thinking if it's possible to buy `JohnDoe.com` and redirect it to `myprofession+city.com`. If I do that and people search for just my name, will `JohnDoe.com` appear in the search results?

Comment: I tried to clarify this a bit, however you tagged it with a [302-redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) which is a _temporary_ redirect. Was it your intention to have it permanently redirect? In that case you'd use a [301](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/301-redirects). Like with browsers, a redirect will tell Googlebot to load the target of that redirect (`myprofession+city.com`) and crawl and index that. So if your name appears in `myprofession+city.com`, then searching for your name in Google would just return results for `myprofession+city.com`...

Comment: You would need to build separate content for `JohnDoe.com`, without a redirect, which contained your name so that Google could index it. Then you could link to your main site `myprofession+city.com` from there, which would help build backlinks and authority.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will having multiple domains improve my seo?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/will-having-multiple-domains-improve-my-seo)

Answer (score 2):

If you buy a personal name domain and redirect it to your main site, no, it will not appear in search results. The 301 redirect will tell search engines that all content for that domain lives on the main site. And if you use a 302 redirect, after a while, major search engines will treat is as a 301 anyway.

If you're just buying a domain to redirect to your main site, there would be no content there to index anyway. The only reason I see for doing this is if you want to list it somewhere and have the visitor go to the original site - like on a business card or on a resume or on LinkedIn.